# Conditional statement to check if post is in 2014

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

How can I check if a post is in a specific year? I need to output some code if the single post is in a specific year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the wp loop you can get the date of the post with the built in wp functino of **the_date('Y')**

So in the wp loop just check to see if the date == something like so.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
      if(the_date('Y') == '2015'):
        the_post(); 
      else:
         continue;
       endif;
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```